# if i have binary string "10 1111 1010".What should i do to convert every 2 bits from binary to decimal =>2 33 22

Tags: c#

one-dimensional string array what should I do to converts every 2 bits from binary to decimal
example:
"10 1111 1010"=>2 33 22
" 11 01 1010"=>  3 1 22

Comment: "what should I do .." - make an attempt at something first.

Comment: @maury844 I think you may be incorrect on that. `1111`<>33 but `11` and `11` is `33`.

Comment: @maury844 those numbers clearly represent bits.. that's just pedantic.

Comment: Break the problem down into smaller, easier problems. First split the string by the spaces, then take pairs of binary numbers, then convert those pairs into decimals. etc...

Comment: @JNevill can you help me ?

Comment: Read the "bits" two at a time, then there are just 4 possibilities that you can handle with a simple `switch`. Possibly add a 0 at one end to create an even number of bits

Comment: What you are requesting is simple the conversion from base 2 to base 4

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Convert.ToInt32`:

```
var binary = "10 1111 1010".Split(' ');
for (var i = 0; i < binary.Length; i++) {
   Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToInt32(binary[i], 2).ToString());
}
// the result is 2 15 10
```

**EDIT**

Suggestion from @JNevill:

Just adding in an inner loop will get you close:

```
    var binary = "10 1111 1010".Split(' ');
    var result = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < binary.Length; i++) {
       for (var j = 0; j < binary[i].Length; j=j+2) {
          result = result + Convert.ToInt32(binary[i].Substring(j,2), 2).ToString();
       }
       result = result + " ";
    }
    Console.WriteLine(result);
 // the result is 2 33 22
```

Comment: Doesn't compile and gives completely the wrong output...

Comment: @DavidG was just because in c sharp split is Split and Writeline is WriteLine....

Comment: But your answer still gives the WRONG output.

Comment: @DavidG No it doesn't: 10 = 2, 1111 = 15; 1010 = 10

Comment: @GiovanniEsposito but the expected result is 2 33 22

Comment: Read the question! It expicitly says `10 1111 1010"=>2 33 22`

Comment: Either way, we generally close questions like this rather than answer them.

Comment: @nghianguyen You need to MAKE SOME EFFORT yourself before asking people here to write all your code for you

Comment: Just adding in an inner loop will get you close, nghia: `for (var j = 0; j < binary[i].Length; j=j+2) {     
    Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToInt32(binary[i].Substring(j,2), 2).ToString());
   }` That should get you console output of 23322. You just need to deal with your spaces in the first loop and you're golden.

Comment: @JNevill can you help me console output 2 33 22

Comment: @nghianguyen I edited the answer. Now function prints exactly `2 33 22`!

Comment: @nghianguyen not at all (I'm Giovanni Esposito anyway, the guy that answered you) =)

Comment: @GiovanniEsposito sorry,i'm wrong,thank you very much =)

Comment: No problem. Happy coding =)